# Как сделать .replace, чтобы добавить в начало найденной строки свой текст, если его нету в начале этой же, найденной строки?

Tags: javascript, регулярные-выражения

Допустим, у меня есть такое регулярное выражение:

```
/((http(s)?:\/\/(www\.)?)?[a-zA-Z]+(\.[a-zA-Z0-9]+)?\.[a-zA-Z0-9]+(\/)?([^\s]*))/g;
```

Оно может словить ссылку toster.ru, так и должно быть, но я использую эту регулярку для поиска ссылок в тексте и заменяю их на теги в этом же тексте вот так:

```
params.text.replace(links_regexp, `<a href="$1" target="_blank">$1</a>`);
```

И, понятное дело, что если http:// или https:// в ссылке нету, то при переходе по этой ссылке, пользователя перебросит на сайт.ру/ссылка, то есть, сосчитает за папку этого сайта. Так вот, как можно добавить в ссылку http://, если его там нету?

Comment: У тебя в регулярке `$1` целая ссылка?

Comment: @RazmikGalstyan да, я же беру в круглые скобки целое выражение

Comment: не можешь взять ссылку по части ? что бы `$1` была часть `http or https` а вторая `www.example.ru/blablabla`?

Comment: @RazmikGalstyan проблема в том, что http там может не быть

Comment: ну значит первая часть то будет `http` то пустая строка? так то же можно писать регулярку.

Comment: @RazmikGalstyan  не очень понимаю, что хотите сказать, можете на коде показать?)

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/60383/discussion-between-razmik-galstyan-and-ikerya).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В качестве второго параметра у метода [.replace(reg, str|func)](https://learn.javascript.ru/regexp-methods#str-replace-reg-str-func) может выступать функция. Например такая:

```js
var text = 'vk.com https://exemple.com';
text = text.replace(/((http(s)?:\/\/(www\.)?)?[a-zA-Z]+(\.[a-zA-Z0-9]+)?\.[a-zA-Z0-9]+(\/)?([^\s]*))/g, 
    function(n0,n1,n2) {
        if (!n2) {
            n1 = 'http://' + n1;
        }
        return '<a href="'+n1+'" target="_blank">'+n1+'</a>';
    });
console.log(text);
```

Comment: Ого! Не знал, благодарю большое!

Answer (score 0):

Вот пример который подойдет вам, если в обсуждении мы правильно поняли друг друга.

```
var links_regexp = '/(http(s)?:\/\/)?((www\.)?)?([a-zA-Z]+(\.[a-zA-Z0-9]+)?\.[a-zA-Z0-9]+(\/)?([^\s]*))/g';

params.text.replace(links_regexp, `<a href="http://$2$3" target="_blank">$2$3</a>`);
```

Я отдельно сделал поиск частей, и часть с `(http:\/\/)?` значит что его может быть а может нет. И всегда мы впихиваем в атрибут `href` вторую часть поиска регулярки, а первая часть всегда пишем в `href`.

Comment: http может и не быть, плюс у меня регулярное выражение универсальное, для всех ссылок. vk.com я использовал для примера

Comment: @ikerya хорошо изменю и скажу

Comment: @ikerya обновил ответ, так сойдет?

Comment: ссылки не видит http://prntscr.com/fjac8o